# What items that can be found inside barrels?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Dark Souls 2 has so many barrels, barrels over here, barrels over there. I have destroy countless of them but unlike any other rpg, there is nothing inside. Are there any items that can be found by destroying those barrels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I believe there are some barrels in **No Man's Wharf** that have an item in them, rolling is the best tactic for destroying objects such as barrels, vases and the like. A tip for vases, if you angle your camera downwards you can peek inside, this is useful if you want to check if they are filled with poison or worse, acid.

Comment: Yep, that's what they call "do a barrel roll !" lol. What sort of item do they drop?

Comment: I don't recall, I may be wrong though. I think they are in the house just by the Pharros erm... socket

Comment: There are also many vases in the gutter with items in them, which you can see by moving the camera as the answer suggested.

Comment: I *think* they damage weapon durability or at least striking the wall next to them during a swing does. Rolling is a good way to avoid this problem.